# xmonad: rotate one screen on dual monitor setup

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xmonad

On Fedora 22 I want to use XMonad as Window-Manager on a dual monitor setup.
I want to rotate one of the monitors but I'm trying to not configure xorg.conf manually like described [here](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/linux-nvidia-xinerama-guide-rotating-just-one-monitor-in-a-dual-head-setup/). (because in my experience auto-configuration can work quite well and is very flexible and much less error-prone)
Is there a way to let XMonad handle the physical monitor setup like it's done with (e.g.) Gnome (i.e. with a configuration for abstract setup like order and rotation of monitors)?

Answer (score 2):

xorg.conf itself is **deprecated** from xserver-1.16. Now is configuration auto-detected and admin/user can modify it in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` **

if you want rotate monitor manually in place is best tool `xrandr`.

for example: `xrandr --output DP1-2 --auto --right-of DP1-1 --rotate left`

this sets monitor on DP1-2 to position right of monitor DP1-1 and rotate it to left

** my 50-monitor.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "eDP1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP1-1"
    Option      "RightOf" "eDP1"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "Primary" "True"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP1-2"
    Option      "RightOf" "DP1-1"
    Option      "Rotate"  "left"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI1"
    Option      "RightOf" "eDP1"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option  "Primary" "True"
EndSection
```